# What environment variables are needed for react-native?

Tags: react-native

I was editing my Path variables and somehow I must've got the Path(environment variable) for react-native lost. When I try to use `react-native run-android` I get the following error `'react-native' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I assume this must be an environment variable issue.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but that didn't help.
I've googled about my issue but that didn't help.

If anyone can share the environment variables , or he suspects something else to be the issue I would really appreciate to be pointed at some direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the path that was missing. It was the `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm` for anyone that might be concerned.